# ¿"Tabla de nieve" o "snowboard"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, deportes

¿Qué es más común escuchar / escribir, *tabla de nieve* o *snowboard*?

Mi maestra (no es una hablante nativa) me dice que es *tabla de nieve* pero sé que en muchos idiomas se usa *snowboard*, como en inglés. ¿Cuál es más común en la lengua vernácula?

Comment: Pues te vas a reír, pero hará unos 25 años cuando a mi familia le dio por el esquí la gente solía decir "tabla de snowboard", o de forma abreviada "tabla de snow". No sé si era algo propio de mi estación de esquí (Sierra Nevada, Andalucía, España) o algo más generalizado.

Comment: Ja ja ja... ¡"Tabla de snow"!

Comment: Te dije que te ibas a reír. :-) En todo caso, sería interesante para obtener respuestas más adecuadas que indicases de qué país eres o de qué país es el español que estás aprendiendo, porque la respuesta podría tener variaciones regionales.

Comment: Realmente me gustaría saber sobre todas variaciones. Viajo en España y Mexico mucho, pero también me gustaría visitar muchos paises en America Sur, pues es bueno tener opciones :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tengo varios conocidos **en España** que practican este deporte de vez en cuando, y las palabras que usan son:

- ***snow*** o ***snowboard*** para referirse al deporte en sí;
- **tabla de *snow*** o simplemente **tabla** para referirse a la tabla.

Ejemplos:

> —El finde nos vamos a Sierra Nevada a hacer ***snow***, ¿te apuntas?
>   —No puedo, se me ha roto la **tabla**.
>
> —Para Navidades me he pillado una **tabla de *snow***. Mis amigos hacen ***snowboard*** todos los años en Reyes y quiero ir con ellos.

Soy consciente de que, si queremos usar el inglés, lo correcto sería usar *snowboarding* para referirse al deporte y *snowboard* para la tabla; pero en mi experiencia no se usan así en español.

*Tabla de nieve* no lo he oído ni leído en mi vida.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Voy a iluminar mi maestra.